# How to get correct DateTime in Dapper

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, .net-core, dapper

I am using Dapper to handle users in ASP.NET Core with SQL Server.
Everything works fine except the `DateTime`.

A correct `DateTime` is stored in the database (04.10.2021 16:11:45), however retrieving it from the database returns a default datetime (0001-01-01T00:00:00).

This is the `User` model class:

```
public class User
{
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

And I use this method in the `User` repository to add a `User` to the database:

```
public async Task<int> AddAsync(User entity)
{
    entity.CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;

    string sql = "insert into users (id, username, email, password, created_at) values (@Id, @Username, @Email, @Password, @CreatedAt)";

    using var connection = new SqlConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("Default"));
    connection.Open();
    var result = await connection.ExecuteAsync(sql, entity);

    return result;
}
```

This is the method that gets the `User` by its id:

```
public async Task<User> GetByIdAsync(string id)
{
    string sql = "select * from users where id = @Id";

    using var connection = new SqlConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("Default"));
    connection.Open();
    var result = await connection.QuerySingleOrDefaultAsync<User>(sql, new { Id = id });

    return result;
}
```

The `User` data is fetched in a controller:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetById(string id)
{
    var data = await _unitOfWork.Users.GetByIdAsync(id);
    if (data == null)
    {
        return Ok();
    }

    return Ok(data);
}
```

The column type of the table is `DATETIME`.

Comment: Can you show the line where you fetch it? i.e. since you say that the problem happens on read, not write, can we see the read? also: perhaps `select ... , created_at as [CreatedAt], ... from ...`

Comment: @MarcGravell I have edited the question showing the controller where the data is fetched.

Comment: Please provide the code inside `GetByIdAsync` method or `select` statement you are using for this operation

Comment: @Alexander I have added the method above

Comment: @TommyTheReal Just `select ... , created_at as [CreatedAt], ... from` as Marc Gravell desribed in his comment

Comment: @MarcGravell Thank you, your solution works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either modify you select statement so it returns `CreatedAt` columns

```
select ... , created_at as [CreatedAt], ... from
```

or make sure your application calls this line at application start

```
Dapper.DefaultTypeMap.MatchNamesWithUnderscores = true;
```